# ASP.NET 5 Identity - refresh roles for a user

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

In `ASP.NET 5`, suppose I have the following controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Super")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Then suppose I have a user, Jack, who has logged in but is *not* a member of the *Super* role.

When Jack tries to access this resource he gets access denied, as expected.

Then, from another machine, I use the UserManager to add him to the *Super* role.

When Jack tries again to access this resource, it is still access denied until he logs out and logs back in again.

How can I make sure that the roles for each user are either not cached, or are refreshed somehow when I make a change?

Answer (score 1):

So here's how I managed to solve this in the end, but really this should be solved with security stamps. The solution below at least provides a "look in" before authorisation happens.

I created a new `AuthorizationHandler` that accepts a `UserManager` in its constructor:

```
public class SuperRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<SuperRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; set; }

    public SuperRequirement(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, SuperRequirement requirement)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override async Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationContext context, SuperRequirement requirement)
    {
        var userName = context.User.Identity.Name;
        var pass = await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName), "Super");
        if (pass)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Fail();
        }
    }
}
```

I then configured this in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    //var service = sp.GetService<ISomeService>();
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Super",
            policy =>
            {
                var userManager = sp.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                policy.Requirements.Add(new SuperRequirement(userManager));
            });
    });
}
```

And finally I updated my controller to use the new authorization policy:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(Policy = "Super")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

This way it checks the database each request to ensure the roles align, using the `UserManager` to do this.

**Please note** this is less efficient as each API request will now trigger extra calls to the database, so you should implement some kind of caching and invalidation mechanism; this is just to demonstrate the principle.